# How to assign alternate class to rows in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to assign alternate class to rows in a table. I am using ng-repeat on

```
<tr ng-repeat="event in events">
```

I want to get output like this:

```
<tr class="odd">...</tr>
<tr class="event">....</tr>
```

I've tried this (doesn't work):

```
<tr ng-repeat="event in events" class="$index % 2 == 0? 'event' : 'odd'">
```

I can't get it to work. Also it seems like Angular is using 'class' attribute to. Why is it doing so? Can I tell AngularJS not to use the class attribute for internal evaluations?

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: This may not be a direct answer to your question, but have a look at [CSS even and odd rules](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html). If you can use those, then you don't need to use classes.

Comment: Thanks! But doesn't actually answer my question(s). :-) Thanks anyways.

Comment: If you're going to build out a table, you might want to check out http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid It's a full-featured angularjs grid we have been working on for the last month.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You should be using the angular directives ngClassEven and ngClassOdd for this.

Have a look at the documentation section for how to use them

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClassEven

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClassOdd

Comment: You could also have done ng-class="$index % 2 == 0 && 'even' || 'odd'".  Angular expressions don't have ternary operators, but you can use the and/or.

Comment: Another options: [`ng-class="['even', 'odd'][$index %2]"`](http://jsfiddle.net/rvKqg/), [`class="{{['even', 'odd'][$index %2]}}"`](http://jsfiddle.net/rvKqg/1/)

Comment: Note: // ng-class="$index % 2 == 0 && 'even' || 'odd'" // approach is slightly more flexible, because it preserves the row-striping even when a filter is applied to the data.

Comment: AngularJS Expressions very much DO have ternary expressions. I use them all the time.

Answer (score 21):

From the Angular docs..

Use **ng-class-odd ng-class-even**

```
<li ng-repeat="name in names">
  <span ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
    {{name}}
  </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 10):

As @ganaraj states ng-class-odd and ng-class-even are the right way to do this, but for the benefit of searchers, your initial proposal wasn't far off working in Angular >=1.2.19.

Here is a closely related example of something that would have worked and would also work if coloring more than alternate rows (e.g. every 3 rows):

```
<div>
<style>
    .color0 {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

    .color1 {
        background-color: lightyellow;
    }

    .color2 {
        background-color: lightgray;
    }
</style>


<div ng-repeat="result in results" ng-class="'color' + ($index % 3)">
    <div>
        <p>{{result.myText}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the `ng-class-odd` and `ng-class-even` directives directly within the `ng-repeat` directive.

```
<div class="cssOneProductRecord" 
   ng-repeat='..' 
   ng-class-odd="'cssProductOdd'" 
   ng-class-even="'cssProductEven'" >
```

Which gives us nice alternating classes for each row:

[image]

This example is taken from the following page, which also demonstrates how to turn JSON data into a friendly, responsive Master-View page:

[Master-Views using AngularJS](http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page8.7.htm)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Improving Fintan Kearney's answer,

From: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd

Style.css

```
.odd {
  color: red;
}
.even {
  color: blue;
}
```

index.html

```
<ol ng-init="names=['John', 'Mary', 'Cate', 'Suz']">
  <li ng-repeat="name in names">
   <span ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
     {{name}}
   </span>
  </li>
</ol>
```