# Bootstrap table with nested ng-repeat striped-rows

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table for which should display striped rows, but since I have nested ng-repeats, my output has groups of rows colored the same instead of striped.  Any way to get the output I'm looking for?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">  
 <tr ng-repeat-start="thing in app.things">
  <td>{{thing.label}}</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat-start="action in thing.actions">
  <td>{{thing.label}}</td>
  <td>{{action.label}}</td>
  <td>&nbsp</td>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="task in action.tasks">
  <td>{{thing.label}}</td>
  <td>{{action.label}}</td>
  <td>{{task.label}}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat-end></tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Check out this answer. [How to Assign Alternate Class To Rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179455/how-to-assign-alternate-class-to-rows-in-angular-js)

Comment: Simplest answer: use `ng-if="false"` on the `ng-repeat-end` row. See my answer below.

Answer (score 10):

**First Option** - Using **CSS**:

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td {
    background-color: #000;
}

.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > td {
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

**Second Option** - Using **CSS and Angular JS** use the **`ng-class-odd="odd"`** and **`ng-class-even="even"`** to add a css class to each tablerow, for example:

```
 <tr ng-repeat-start="action in thing.actions" ng-class-odd="odd" ng-class-even="even">
      <td>{{thing.label}}</td>
      <td>{{action.label}}</td>
      <td>&nbsp</td>
 </tr>
```

And your CSS add the odd and even class, for example:

```
.odd { background-color: #000; }
.even { background-color: #F00; }
```

I hope help you.

Comment: Using your suggestion is not giving me the output I'm expecting.  See here http://plnkr.co/edit/3pqsccyOMGMPW0pxD5mc?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

This isnt really an angular question, it is a css question.  I would have to question your data structure if this is the way you have to make tables.  But what you can do is place all the grouped rows into a tbody tag then create a little custom styles to apply the stripe on tbody.  Drop the table-striped class and then you could do something like this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="action in thing.actions">
    <tr>
        <td>{{thing.label}}</td>
        <td>{{action.label}}</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="action in thing.actions">
        <td>{{thing.label}}</td>
         <td>{{action.label}}</td>
         <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="task in action.tasks">
         <td>{{thing.label}}</td>
         <td>{{action.label}}</td>
         <td>{{task.label}}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>{{thing.label}}</td>
        <td>{{action.label}}</td>
        <td>{{task.label}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

tbody:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Tiago answer - you must remove "table-striped" from the table class, because it overriding the ng-class-odd / ng-class-even CSS classes

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `tbody` element, like

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">  
 <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="thing in app.things">
     ....
```

and add this rule to the CSS:

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-repeat-end` row is causing the stripe issue.

You need the row for AngularJs to do the repeating, but you don't want it for the browser/Bootstrap/css to alternate the styling.

So simply remove it from the table once Angular has used it:

```
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="false"></tr>
```